# How to disable MFA after sandbox refresh?

Tags: sandbox-refresh, two-factor-authentication, mfa, multi-factor-authentication

I do have an org with a permission set to force some users to set up MFA. How do I remove the MFA connection for all users after I refresh the sandbox? I can certainly remove them from the permission set but this will only remove the requirement - not the actual MFA connection.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you asking for a programmatic way or just how to do it? There's the following [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_disconnect_verification_methods.htm&type=5) that shows you there's `App Registration` fields on the user object for Salesforce Authenticator (and another for other apps) where you can click `disconnect`.

Comment: Why do you need to disconnect them, what problem are you trying to solve

Comment: Yes - a programmatic way. Users are annoyed by wiring up their Salesforce Authenticator every single time after a refresh. The CEO decided that it would be great to disable MFA on sandboxes completely.

Comment: Then why not just delete all the permission set assignments for MFA as you mentioned in the question? That will remove the requirement and seems to be your actual problem (users being required to do MFA in sandbox). The connection doesn't matter if it's connected/disconnected if you're not asking them to do MFA in the first place. You could look at [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) (not sure if Automated Process can remove PSA or not) or just use anonymous apex to do it.

Comment: Of course, I can remove the permission set assignment but the users would still have to remove the connection manually after setting up the MFA again after the refresh. Which kind of defeats its purpose.

Comment: If MFA isn't enforced via permset/profile, why would the users have to set up the Authenticator in a sandbox after it's refreshed?

Comment: They don't. It is automatically set up after the refresh but needs to be re-wired on the first login as it is still active from production. That's the step that the users don't like.

Comment: what does "re-wired" mean in this context? I can't, unfortunately, test this to see for myself but not sure if you'd have a screenshot of what the users see when logging in if MFA isn't required (my assumption would be they just login with no issues).

Comment: @KrisGoncalves It simply means that the first time after the refresh your user is still "connected" to the MFA and if you just try to log in then you will have to confirm this in your Salesforce Authenticator. You would have to disconnect every user first.

Comment: You can perform the following queries to find profiles (select id, Name,  PermissionsForceTwoFactor from Profile where PermissionsForceTwoFactor = true) and Permission Sets (select id, Name,  PermissionsForceTwoFactor from PermissionSet where PermissionsForceTwoFactor = true and IsOwnedByProfile = false) where it is turned on. Then you can do a data load to set PermissionsForceTwoFactor on Profiles/Permission Sets to false. However, I am not able to find anything on the user records to remove MFA connection. Not sure if clearing PermissionsForceTwoFactor on Prof/PS will clear user records.